# Copying all .desktop files to ~/.local/share/applications/

Tags: linux, bash, gnome, xdgutils

I'm trying to write a bash script to copy all `.desktop` files under `/nix/store` to `~/.local/share/applications/`. I'm not particular good with bash, so I would like assistance. I used the `find` command to find all files. Now I'm trying to create an array from the output with the help of `readarray`:

```
files=$(find /nix/store -type f -name \*.desktop)
echo $files
x=$(readarray -d 's'  <<<$files)
echo $x
```

The `echo $files` will print the result of the `find` command, however the `echo $x` prints an empty line.

Comment: Please try `cp -p /nix/store/*.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`.

Comment: Your find command will confuse any paths or names containing spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=$(find /nix/store -type f -name \*.desktop)

readarray array <<<$files

for i in ${array[@]}; do
    cp $i ~/.loca/share/applications/
done
```

or

```
find /nix/store -type f -name \*.desktop -exec cp {} ~/.local/share/applications/ \;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Copying all .desktop files to ~/.local/share/applications/

```
find /nix/store -type f -name '*.desktop' \
   -exec cp -v {} ~/.local/share/applications/ ';'
```

> however the echo $x prints an empty line.

`readarray` produces **no output**. Instead, it *stores* the lines in the argument, which represents the name of the variable, the name of the array.

```
readarray -d 's'  <<<$files
#            ^^^  - stores output in array named s
printf "%s\n" "${s[@]}"  # you can print the array s
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong and /nix/store/ is a regular directory, this should work:

```
cp /nix/store/*.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```